# how to add a certain icon for a certain document for multiple file upload with preview

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code with which I can preview the multiple uploaded files. I made the icon appear for any loaded document.
However, it is impossible to make so that for a certain document there is a certain icon

How can this be done?

Code:

```js
let file_array = [];

function scrollBottom() {
  let element = document.querySelector('.chat-item-body');
  element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight - element.clientHeight;
}

scrollBottom();

$("#chat-file").change(function() {
  let input_files = document.getElementById('chat-file').files;

  $.each(input_files, function(index, value) {
    file_array.push(value);
    $('.preview__container').append(`
            <div class="preview__content">
                <div class="img"><img src="/img/fileType.png" alt=""></div>
                <p>${value.name}</p>
                <i class="far fa-times-circle delete_file" data-id="${file_array.length - 1}"></i>
  <p class="delete_file" data-id="${file_array.length - 1}">x</p>
            </div>
            `);
  });
});

$(document.body).on('click', '.delete_file', function() {
  let file_id = $(this).data('id');
  delete file_array[file_id];
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="chat-item-body">
  <label class="label-file" for="chat-file">
            <i class="icon i-clip"></i>
            <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple="" id="chat-file" />
          </label>
  <div class="preview__container">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: My result]

now I have result that you can see on image, but I want to have different image for different documents
How can this be done?

Comment: Do you want to add the FA icon for the type of file that is being loaded, so your `<i class="far fa-times-circle delete_file" data-id="${file_array.length - 1}"></i>` would display the font awsome version of say an image icon if the file type is a ***.jpg***?

Comment: I want to upgrade - if I attach a .pdf document, then the pdf icon is displayed, if .doc, then another icon